# Regex.Replace - HELP!

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to do what should be a simple pattern match and replace:

```
Regex.Replace(sUserSettings, @"Name={could_be_anything};", "Name=Tim;");
```

I have been try along the lines of:

```
Regex.Replace(sUserSettings, @"Name=\*[];", "Name=Tim;");
```

No joy - where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[]` matches nothing.

To match anything (ungreedily), use `.*?`:

```
Regex.Replace(sUserSettings, @"Name=\*.*+?;", "Name=Tim;");
```

Now, I'm not sure why you need to match an asterisk first (`\*`). If it doesn't matter, you can leave it out:

```
Regex.Replace(sUserSettings, @"Name=.*?;", "Name=Tim;");
```

Comment: Why do you have the `\*` in there? That matches a literal *.

Comment: I think that was part of his original attempt at `.+?` behavior. Judging by his sample input, anyway.

Answer (score 1):

```
Regex.Replace( sUserSettings, @"(^|;)Name=[^;]*(;)?", "$1Name=Tim$2" )
```

This allows you to replace it even if it's at the beginning or end end of the string without a trailing `;`.